# Position of structure of as+a+[noun] in sentences

Tags: meaning

> The only complaint that I have about you **as a housemate** is ...
>
> **As a housemate**, the only complaint that I have about you is ...

What do the expressions in bold refer to: 'I' or 'you' (i.e. my housemate)?

Comment: In the first sentence it would normally be taken that 'as a homemate' is modifying the noun phrase immediately preceding it (_you_). But it's not demanded: 'The only thing I have to do for her as a carer is ...'. Similarly, in sentences like the second, a modifier would normally be taken to be modifying the nearest acceptable noun phrase. 'As a member, the only way I can allow you to ....)' ((_I_ here, not _the only way_, of course). But context is important; most people would assume 'As a homemate' to be modifying 'you' in this example, as this seems to describe the more likely scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> *The only complaint that I have about you as a house-mate is ...*

- The *as a house-mate* applies to the *you*.  It is unambiguous, because *you as a house-mate* identifies the characteristics of the *you*.
- This would be less ambiguous still (notice the comma):

  *The only complaint that I have, about you as a house-mate is ...*

> *As a house-mate, the only complaint that I have about you is ...*

- The *as a house-mate* applies to the *I*.  It is unambiguous, because it states the basis of *I*.
- Do not be confused by the second clause, and the positioning of the subject-verb-object.  It could have been stated differently, but it is still one whole and complete clause:

  *As a house-mate, I have only one complaint about you, which is ...*

In single sentence with one clause, you can play with the sequence of subject-verb-object, to obtain an effect, it does not change the subject or the object.  But when you have a sentence that is made up of more than one clause, and particularly when a clause is a fragment (*as a house-mate* is not a complete sentence), the object of the application of that fragment can be ambiguous.  It used to be that it applies to the nearest object, but meaning overrides that (an incorrect application that doesn't make sense can be eliminated).

At the end of the day, the distinction in this particular exaple does not matter, because you are both house-mate of each other.

> **Obsolete**
>
> Last, *homemate* is not English, *house-mate* is.  There are connotations on the word *home*, that *house* does not have, and vice versa.  I can accept that you share your house with someone, but not that you share your home with them.  In the latter case, they would be family, and you wouldn't call family *homemates*.